# How to turn on Touch ID + Automatic Login with macOS on MacBook Pro with Touch ID key?

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, security, login, touch-id

I would like to find a way to change a preference option from the shell or another way to force macOS 12 (Monterey)+ to allow one to use BOTH the `Touch ID` functionality along with automatic login for a user.

In my case my laptop is used in a very secure environment - always. I have no need for this feature coupling and therefore would like to decouple them and use both. With automatic login turned on and when I try to enable `Touch ID` I get the following error message:
[image: touch id error in system preferences]

I want to bypass this and I have to think there is a policy or setting that could be modified via a `.plist` or other method.

Comment: I think Touch ID enabled will not allow you to automatically log in. With FileVault turned on, you are not allow you to automatically log in. https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201476 What if you turn FileVault off, does that make a difference?

Comment: TouchID even demands you type the password at reboot [there's a minimum time for this, possibly 48h] so I very much doubt it's going to be possible. iOS does the same for Touch ID.